# Reflection requies type annotation

Tags: reflection, rust

I am trying to hide the type information of the `impl Foo` and store this information for later use. Is this even possible?

```
#![feature(universal_impl_trait)]

use std::any::Any;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Foo {
    type Item;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item;
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Bar<T: Clone>(T);
impl<T: Clone> Bar<T> {
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Bar(t)
    }
}
impl<T: 'static + Clone> Foo for Bar<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item {
        self.0.clone()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Baz<T: Clone, F: Clone>(T, F);
impl<T: Clone, F: Clone> Baz<T, F> {
    fn new(t: T, f: F) -> Self {
        Baz(t, f)
    }
}
impl<T: 'static + Clone, F: 'static + Clone> Foo for Baz<T, F> {
    type Item = (T, F);
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item {
        (self.0.clone(), self.1.clone())
    }
}

trait Get {
    type Item;
    fn idx(&self) -> usize;
}

struct GetBar<T> {
    id: usize,
    _t: PhantomData<T>,
}
impl<T> Get for GetBar<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn idx(&self) -> usize {
        self.id
    }
}
impl<T> GetBar<T> {
    fn new(id: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            id,
            _t: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

struct GetBaz<T, F> {
    id: usize,
    _t: PhantomData<T>,
    _f: PhantomData<F>,
}
impl<T, F> Get for GetBaz<T, F> {
    type Item = T;
    fn idx(&self) -> usize {
        self.id
    }
}
impl<T, F> GetBaz<T, F> {
    fn new(id: usize) -> Self {
        GetBaz {
            id,
            _t: PhantomData,
            _f: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

struct Qux {
    v: Vec<Box<Any>>,
}
impl Qux {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Qux { v: vec![] }
    }

    fn add_bar<T: 'static + Clone>(&mut self, a: T) -> GetBar<T> {
        self.v.push(Box::new(Bar::new(a)) as Box<Any>);
        GetBar::new(self.v.len())
    }

    fn add_baz<T: 'static + Clone, F: 'static + Clone>(&mut self, a: T, b: F) -> GetBaz<T, F> {
        self.v.push(Box::new(Baz::new(a, b)) as Box<Any>);
        GetBaz::new(self.v.len())
    }

    fn get<T: 'static + Clone, F: 'static + Clone>(&self, val: &'static impl Get) -> Option<T> {
        let node = &self.v[val.idx()];
        if let Some(foo) = node.downcast_ref::<Bar<T>>() {
            Some(foo.get())
        } else if let Some(foo) = node.downcast_ref::<Baz<T, F>>() {
            Some(foo.get().0)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut qux = Qux::new();

    let a = qux.add_bar(1_i32);
    let b = qux.add_bar("1");
    let c = qux.add_baz(Bar::new('A'), Bar::new('B'));

    assert_eq!(qux.get(&a).unwrap(), 1);
    assert_eq!(qux.get(&b).unwrap(), "i");
    assert_eq!(qux.get(&c).unwrap(), Bar::new('A'));
}
```

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: std::clone::Clone`
   --> src/main.rs:121:20
    |
121 |     assert_eq!(qux.get(&a).unwrap(), 1);
    |                    ^^^
```

Sorry for the long example but this is the best I can do.

I'm trying to reconcile the Rust static type system with dynamically dispatched trait objects. However, in many occasions I am unable to provide type annotations. What is the best way to achieve this? How can I dynamically supply type information to the trait object system?

What about `qux.add_baz(GetBar::<&str>::new(1), GetBaz::<i32, i32>::new(3));` and use that type information to recursively get from `qux`?

Sorry for the contrived example; the [real code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/rickyhan/spandex-rs/blob/0bc3d4c4aff8b6cbedda9702e3c741e2f9ece443/src/lib.rs).

Comment: I am confused by your question. I see no dynamic dispatch in it, nor any suggestion on how you want the `Foo` trait to be used in general. Note that the trait is not [object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html#object-safety), so you cannot dynamically dispatch through it. Also, your question title mentions "reflection", which Rust doesn't have and which has nothing to do with trait object dynamic dispatch.

Comment: You are right this cannot be a trait object, though, correct me if I'm wrong, dynamic dispatch happens when `Box<Any>` gets downcast to appropriate trait objects ie `Box<Bar>`. Basically I am trying to hide the associated type of the `Foo` trait and store this information for later use. Is this even possible? What about `qux.add_baz(GetBar::<&str>::new(1), GetBaz::<i32, i32>::new(3));` and use that type information to recursively get from `qux`? Sorry for the contrived example, the real repo is https://github.com/rickyhan/spandex-rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What's the code that you would like to write to *use* this trait?

Comment: @DanHulme I'd like to achieve something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9c752a5c8a477ae08e8b2532e07c3168&version=stable

Comment: Wow, I completely failed to scroll down in the code box. I'll have  closer look now.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want type-aware keys that you can use to get the typed values out again. But it's extra tricky, because you have two different kinds of values, and you want to use a single key interface to support either of them.